# How to raise property changed event from outside of Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

Entities already implement the PropertyChanged. If properties are changed, PropertyChanged will be fired.
What I want now is: I want to fire PropertyChanged event in code even the value actually not changed (for binding purpose). I want to do something like from outside of the entity:

```
MyEntity.RaisedPropertyChanged("myProperty");
```

Also know that Entities have OnPropertyChanged method, but it is protected, only available inside the class or its subclass.

How to implement this request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else might point out a why you shouldn't have to do this, but one simple thing is to add a public method that relays to the protected method.

```
public partial class MyEntity
{    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
       this.RaisedPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. tried and found it is easy to cause dead loop and crash the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method inside a partial class for `MyEntity` that fires calls the protected method.